# using foreach and %dopar% to output the desired results

Tags: r

So in a simplistic world, lets take this data:

```
set.seed(123)

require(doParallel)
cl<-makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

m <- 10

Result = foreach(i=1:m,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {

  rows <- (1:10)
  A <- rnorm(10, 5, 1)
  A <- round(A, 0)

  B <- rnorm(10, 6, 1)
  B <- round(B, 0)

  df <- data.frame(rows,A,B)

  output_1 <- length(df$A[df$A == df$B])
  # save the number of accounts where A == B
  output_2 <- length(df$A[df$A != df$B])
  # save the number of accounts where A  and B are not equal

  Result <- rbind(output_1,output_2)

}
```

Using this we can check our output

```
Result[1,]
Result[2,]
```

But now I want to include the rows (a string of row identities, not the count) that correspond to A!=B in the output of the Result

The problem is that this is not a single value and it varies per alteration. How can one achieve this?

**update**

if we add something like

```
output_3 <- setdiff(df$rows, df$rows[df$A == df$B])
```

and adjust

```
Result <- rbind(output_1,output_2, output_3)
```

We run more simulations than required

Comment: You could return a list of vectors with your row identities, that way each list element could be whatever length you need.

Comment: ok, how so? can you elaborate please?

Comment: I can't work through your code at the moment, but have a look at `lapply` which will iterate over an input and return a list.

Comment: @MikeRSpencer `foreach` also returns a list if not told otherwise.

Comment: Sounds like they're on the right path then. Danger is ending up with a list of a list of a list of a list...

Comment: Maybe return `Result <- data.frame(i = i, unequals = which(df$A != df$B)); Result` and use `.combine = rbind`? The lengths you can compute after the loop. Actually, you don't need a loop at all. The whole simulation could be done fully vectorized.

Comment: But I want to save `output_1` and `output_2`

Comment: Why? It's easy to calculate after the loop. If you insist on this, you need to return a list and will get a list of list fron the loop (e.g., can't specify a non-default `.combine` function).

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you could submit as a solution, so I can understand how it is obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you apparently desire:

```
set.seed(123)

require(doParallel)
cl<-makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

m <- 10

Result = foreach(i=seq_len(m)) %dopar% {

  rows <- (1:10)
  A <- rnorm(10, 5, 1)
  A <- round(A, 0)

  B <- rnorm(10, 6, 1)
  B <- round(B, 0)

  df <- data.frame(rows,A,B)

  output_1 <- length(df$A[df$A == df$B])
  # save the number of accounts where A == B
  output_2 <- length(df$A[df$A != df$B])
  # save the number of accounts where A  and B are not equal

  list(rbind(output_1, output_2), which(df$A != df$B))

}
stopCluster(cl)
```

This returns a list of lists. Note that you need to use package doRNG if you want to pass the random seed to the workers.

This is the vectorized approach I would use:

```
set.seed(42)
A <- matrix(round(rnorm(m * 10, 5, 1), 0), ncol = m)
B <- matrix(round(rnorm(m * 10, 6, 1), 0), ncol = m)

which(A != B, arr.ind = TRUE)
colSums(A != B)
colSums(A == B)
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the assistance. My example has matrix of different sizes, so to keep it simple i will stay away form the second method. One question with the `forloop`command. How can inspect the third part of the list, ie. `Result[[1:m]][[2]]` ?

Comment: or something like `c(Result[[1:m]][[2]])`?

Comment: It is worth taking some time to come up with a vectorized approach if your `m` gets large. Regarding your second question: You need to use `lapply` for that.

Comment: using something like this `unlist(lapply(Result, function(x), print[[1:m]]))`?

Comment: Try `lapply(Result, "[[", 2)`.

Comment: And if we want to output a string of integers from output_1 ?

Comment: Try parsing what the code in my previous comment does, study `help("lapply")`,  and you should be able to solve this yourself.